# How do I make a multiple page PDF from a textView?

Tags: ios, pdf

I generated a PDF file from my iPhone app and while most of the documents are only one page, I want to be able detect if the text is going to go outside of the "margins" and if so, add it to the next page.  I am new to this so not really sure how to do this.

Below is the code.  Any suggestions?

```
- (void) drawBorder
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    CGRect rectFrame = CGRectMake(kBorderInset, kBorderInset, pageSize.width-kBorderInset*2, pageSize.height-kBorderInset*2);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, borderColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, kBorderWidth);
    CGContextStrokeRect(currentContext, rectFrame);
}

- (void)drawPageNumber:(NSInteger)pageNumber
{
    NSString* pageNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %d", pageNumber];
    UIFont* theFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

    CGSize pageNumberStringSize = [pageNumberString sizeWithFont:theFont
                                               constrainedToSize:pageSize
                                                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGRect stringRenderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset,
                                            pageSize.height - 40.0,
                                            pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset,
                                            pageNumberStringSize.height);

    [pageNumberString drawInRect:stringRenderingRect withFont:theFont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
}

- (void) drawHeader:(NSString *)header
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    NSString *textToDraw = header;

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0];

    CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

    [textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
}

- (void) drawText:(NSString *)bodyText
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    NSString *textToDraw = bodyText;

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font
                               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) 
                                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 50.0, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

    [textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect 
                  withFont:font
             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
                 alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

}

- (void) drawLine
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, kLineWidth);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(kMarginInset + kBorderInset, kMarginInset + kBorderInset + 40.0);
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(pageSize.width - 2*kMarginInset -2*kBorderInset, kMarginInset + kBorderInset + 40.0);

    CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

    CGContextClosePath(currentContext);    
    CGContextDrawPath(currentContext, kCGPathFillStroke);
}

- (void) drawImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    //UIImage * demoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"demo.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake( (pageSize.width - image.size.width/2)/2, 350, image.size.width/2, image.size.height/2)];
}


- (void) generatePdf: (NSString *)thefilePath :(NSString *) theHeader :(NSString *) theText :(UIImage *) theImage
{

    pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 792);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

    NSInteger currentPage = 0;
    BOOL done = NO;
    do 
    {
        //Start a new page.
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

        //Draw a page number at the bottom of each page.
        currentPage++;
        [self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

        //Draw a border for each page.
        [self drawBorder];

        //Draw text fo our header.
        [self drawHeader:theHeader];

        //Draw a line below the header.
        [self drawLine];

        //Draw some text for the page.
        [self drawText:theText];

        //Draw an image
        [self drawImage:theImage];
        done = YES;
    } 
    while (!done);

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)generatePdfWithFileName:(id)sender
{
    pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 792);
    NSString *fileName = @"test.pdf";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSString *header = @"This is the bad ass header section!";
    NSString *text = @"There is so much to say here I don't know where to begin....";

    [self generatePdf : pdfFileName : header:text:nil];
}

@end
```

Comment: As far as I know you have to keep track of your current Y coordinate and update with each item you add.  When you are at or close to the margin, you start a new page.  If using a cloud-service is an option, you could try something like Docmosis which manages page layouts itself.  Doesn't help you if you are committed to laying out the document in code like this.

Comment: Can you give me an idea how to go about this?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer since it's too large for a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The concept can be seen here

[from [http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=160]](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=160)

When placing items, get the Height:

```
CGSize size = [name sizeWithFont:studentNameFont forWidth:maxWidth lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[name drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(kMargin, currentPageY) forWidth:maxWidth withFont:studentNameFont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
currentPageY += size.height;
```

At appropriate points, check the currentY and decide if you need to move to a new page:

```
if (size.height + currentPageY > maxHeight) {
// create a new page and reset the current page's Y value
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, kDefaultPageWidth, kDefaultPageHeight), nil);
currentPageY = kMargin;
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: This answer don't tells if a string is too much long. How to break it into parts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to stackoverflow but I would like to suggest a brief answer to the "break into parts a long text view" problem.

The method I use is surely not the most efficient way to break a text into parts but it's the only way i found and it works.
Taking a part of a text, i just check in a loop, before drawing, word by word if the sub-text fit in my page, meaning height permitted. If the whole text doesn't fit then my code will only draw the part found. For instance, I could break a long text into four pages..., at least.
Sorry for my lack of experience and if my answer, that is just a glimpse, an idea of "how to", is not clear enough.

To clarify my answer. I added the method I use to check the height needed (found) for a "sub-text" (checking every time with a word added to the "sub-text"). Because "sizeWithFont:" is deprecated since IOS 7, I use "boundingRectWithSize:" method.

```
// Process, that can take long though, to find the next start of the part of a text that hasn't been drawned yet.

float widthRect;
widthRect = pageWidth - 2 * leftMargin;

    - (unsigned int) findNextStartingPos:(NSString *)text withHeight:(float) height
    {
        NSString *character;
        unsigned int pos = 0;
        unsigned int posFound = 0;
        unsigned int lastPosFound = 0;
        BOOL found = NO;
        NSString *textTest;
        float heightFound;

        while (pos <= [text length]-1)
        {
            character = [text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(pos, 1)];
            if ([character isEqualToString:@" "] || [character isEqualToString:@"\n"])
            {
                posFound = pos;
                found = YES;
            }

            if (found)
            {
                textTest = [text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, posFound)];
                heightFound = lroundf([self heightFound:textTest withWidth:widthRect fontSize:fontSizeBody center:NO]);

                if (heightFound > height)
                {
                    if (lastPosFound == 0)
                    {
                        posFound = lastPosFound;
                    } else
                    {
                        posFound = lastPosFound + 1;
                    }
                    if (posFound > [text length]-1) posFound = lastPosFound;
                    break;
                }
                lastPosFound = posFound;
            }
            pos++;
        }

        return posFound;

    }  return posFound;

    }


// Returns the height needed to draw a text (and to check for space in a page)
-(float) heightFound:(NSString *)text withWidth:(float)width fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize center:(BOOL)center
{
    if ([text length] != 0)
    {
        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize];

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        if (center)
        {
            paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        } else {
            paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        }
        NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle};

        NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributes];

        CGRect newRect = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX} options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];

        return newRect.size.height;

    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if my my code was'nt precise enoungh. It would have been too long.

Comment: Beware of a page that would end with a "\n", it would need more coding.

Comment: I don't really seek for "points reputation", but since I'm new on Stackoverflow, some encouragements would be well appreciated.